# Find Average Time

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find the average time. of students exam taken time. i have start time and end time. and total count.
but its gives error on line.

```
$start_dateav = new DateTime($start_time_av);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (19/12/2015
>   01:55:13 pm) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character' in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mock\report.php:117 Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mock\report.php(117):
>   DateTime->__construct('19/12/2015 01:5...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mock\report.php on line 117

```
function average_time($total, $count, $rounding = 0) {
    $total = explode(":", strval($total));
    if (count($total) !== 3) return false;
    $sum = $total[0]*60*60 + $total[1]*60 + $total[2];
    $average = $sum/(float)$count;
    $hours = floor($average/3600);
    $minutes = floor(fmod($average,3600)/60);
    $seconds = number_format(fmod(fmod($average,3600),60),(int)$rounding);
    return $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
}

$sqlav="select * from user_test where test_id = '$test_id'";
$resultav=mysqli_query($con,$sqlav);
$takentimeavH = "0";
$takentimeavM = "0";
$takentimeavS = "0";
$totaltst = "3237";
while ($totaltstav=mysqli_fetch_array($resultav)) {
    $start_time_av=date('d/m/Y h:i:s a',strtotime($totaltstav['start_time']));
    $end_time_av=date('d/m/Y h:i:s a',strtotime($totaltstav['end_time']));
    $start_dateav = new DateTime($start_time_av);
    $since_startav = $start_dateav->diff(new DateTime($end_time_av));
    $takentimeavH += $since_startav->h;
    $takentimeavM += $since_startav->i;
    $takentimeavS += $since_startav->s;
}
$tataltime = $takentimeavH.':'.$takentimeavM.':'.$takentimeavS;

echo average_time($tataltime, $totaltst);
```

on the same php page i am using the same method to get time. its working fine.

```
$sqlm="select * from user_test where test_id = '$test_id' order by mark desc limit 1";
$resultm=mysqli_query($con,$sqlm);
$totaltstm=mysqli_fetch_array($resultm);
$maxmarkss=$totaltstm['mark'];
$start_time_toppr=date('d/m/Y h:i:s a',strtotime($totaltstm['start_time']));
$end_time_toppr=date('d/m/Y h:i:s a',strtotime($totaltstm['end_time']));
$start_datetppr = new DateTime($start_time_toppr);
$since_starttppr = $start_datetppr->diff(new DateTime($end_time_toppr));
$takentimetppr = $since_starttppr->h.':'.$since_starttppr->i.':'.$since_starttppr->s.'';
```

Comment: Why not do this in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved i use the Date **Y-m-d** instead of **d/m/Y**